# Support different orientations on iPhone & iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ipad

I want to support both portrait and landscape on iPad, but only portrait on iPhone.
Is it possible? What is the best way to do this?

There's only one set of "Device orientation" checkboxes in the project settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There's only one set of "Device orientation" checkboxes in the project settings.

Yes, and you use it like this:

1. Check just iPhone.
2. Check just portrait.
3. Check just iPad.
4. Check all four orientations.
5. Check both iPhone and iPad.

I know it's confusing, but that will do what you want.

Comment: I did this (In general > Deployment info), but when I run the app on my iPhone, it still rotates. And nothing appeared in the info.plist after doing this.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong info.plist display. Edit the project and look in the Info tab.  You will see.

Comment: I am looking into this Info.plist: https://imgur.com/a/ahFGLXZ

Comment: And I'm telling you that's  the wrong one. Do what I said.

Comment: Oh, so it's this one: https://imgur.com/a/ZM3cWK1 Thank you :)
Why there are three "Supported interface orientations"? There's "Supported interface orientations (iPhone)", "Supported interface orientations (iPad)" and "Supported interface orientations". What is this third one for?

Comment: Well done. Delete the _first_ one and you're all set.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the `info.plist` file as per your needs manually.

Notice, iPad orientation is separate from the default phone orientation.

[image]